# Set project base URL in functional testing with Laravel 5 / Codeception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, functional-testing, codeception, base-url

Is there a way to dynamically set the project URL during Laravel 5 Codeception functional tests ?

Currently, the base URL is `localhost` but I try to write a test for a PDF generation with the [Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) module and the binary returns and error because my css sheet is not charged (the binary need an absolute path).

I have set an `.env.testing` file configured with my testing database configuration and the `APP_URL` path specified with my app url but it does not change anything. The base URL is still `localhost`during my tests.

Would you think it could be possible to overwrite the base URL during my functional testing ?

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel 5.4 i use this in my PHPUnit tests, probably it'll work with Codeception too:

```php
\URL::forceRootUrl('http://my.root.url.com');
```